# Prove that the number of solutions of $a.x^m + b.y^n = c \mod p$ same as $ax^{m'} + by^{n'} =c \mod p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question found in Ireland and Rosen's "A classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory", Ch4 Q22. The question was as follows.

> Q. Prove that the number of solutions (x,y) to the equation  $a.x^m + b.y^n = c \cdot \mod(p)$ is the same as the number of solutions to the equation $ax^{m'} + by^{n'} = c \cdot \mod(p)$ where p is a prime and $m' =(m,p-1)$ and $n'=(n,p-1)$. I tried to construct a one-one map between the two solution sets but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Is $p$ prime or any number?

Comment: Solutions to what variables?

Comment: My apologies for not making that clear. p is a prime number and the solutions are to the the variables x and y.